# access to xrdp localhost webserver from my navigator

Tags: remote-access, redmine, rdp, xorg, xrdp

its been a while since i ve been stucked with this.

i created a redmine application on a xRDP and everything is alright, i can lunch it with puma or rails, without issues. but when i go to my chrome and try to Access to my application a write : 172.x.x.x:3000 and i have

```
Ce site est inaccessible 172.x.x.x a mis trop de temps à répondre.
Voici quelques conseils :

Vérifier la connexion
Vérifier le proxy et le pare-feu
Exécutez les diagnostics réseau de Windows
ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT"
```

the log when i start the server with : `puma -e production -p 3000`

```
Puma starting in single mode...
* Puma version: 5.6.2 (ruby 2.7.0-p0) ("Birdie's Version")
*  Min threads: 0
*  Max threads: 5
*  Environment: production
*          PID: 78413
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.6/lib/active_record/associations.rb:1855: warning: Using the last argument as keyword parameters is deprecated; maybe ** should be added to the call
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.6/lib/active_record/associations.rb:1368: warning: The called method `has_many' is defined here
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:37: warning: Using the last argument as keyword parameters is deprecated; maybe ** should be added to the call
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:111: warning: The called method `initialize' is defined here
* Listening on http://0.0.0.0:3000
Use Ctrl-C to stop
```

to resume i want to access to my xRPD redmine from my navigator so everyone can use it without using the remote controle.

if you got any ideas i will be gratefull, Thank you guys for your help

Answer (score 0):

i found the issue, the probleme was the port 3000 (IN/OUT) that wasnt open on the Xrdp, i hope that this will help anyone that have the same issue.
Best regards